# Dragon shifter romance series

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons

I read this book series a long time ago and I loved it but I can’t find it back. It’s a book series that has four dragon shifter males that are mated to four different women and the story point of views are from the women.

The women are all 19 years old. The eldest brother is named Lexen. The first book of the series its cover has a girl with purple hair standing in front of a house gate and she is wearing a school uniform.

She and her parents moved to this place because they couldn’t afford to live somewhere else and all the houses were tiny and close together and the hot water was like very limited. But when she moves in she looks across the street and sees the four brothers because they are the only ones in the neighborhood who live in the big house and that’s the only big house in the city. But one night she sees a weird glow in their backyard and decides to follow them in the light only to be transported to their dragon world.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  It's not clear when "a long time ago" was, this past March or 1996.

Answer (score 5):

This must be the *Secret Keepers* series by Jaymin Eve. The first in the four book series is *[House of Darken](https://www.goodreads.com/es/book/show/36161602-house-of-darken)*. The summary from Goodreads confirms the main details:

> When Emma moves to Astoria, Oregon, she is given two rules:
>
> #1 – Don’t cross to “their” side of the street.
>
> #2 – Don’t mess with the elites, especially Lexen Darken, top elite and resident bad boy.
>
> While she finds this both weird and insulting, Emma has no actual
> intention of breaking these rules - until her guardians go missing.
> Now all bets are off. Only a single line separates her side of the
> street from the elites', and she's crossing it.
>
> Captured and held by Lexen and his brothers, she learns the rules are
> in place for a very good reason. There's a secret world hidden in this
> small town which goes far beyond the one she knows and understands.
>
> A world not for humans.

The book cover indeed shows a girl standing in front of a gate.

[image: Cover of "House of Darken", showing a girl in front of a gate]

Comment: Beat me to it by 8 seconds. Mostly because I was busily writing up a funny comment instead of diligently searching for it :-)

Comment: You guys are just too much faster than me; I was still reading through the reviews. :D

Comment: @DavidW - I had the fastest gun, but it was still in my holster and I shot myself in the foot with it.

Comment: Um, I'm not seeing any purple hair...

Comment: @Martha Fair enough, it seemed more purple in a different image.

Comment: Same author - https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1619725430i/57894974.jpg